# Sub menu using same color as top menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I am creating a menu for the theme I am creating. The problem I am having is if the page I am on has a drop down, the sub menu's will have the same color as the top item where I want it to match the rest of the menu, in this case, white with black text. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Example

[image]

**EDIT**

Code to produce the menu (this is a wordpress theme, so there isn't much code required)

```
<nav class="site-nav">                  
    <?php 
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'container_class' => 'main-nav',
        'container' => 'nav',
    )); 
    ?>
</nav>
```

Code to register the menu (if needed)

```
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
    //'sidebar' => __( 'Sidebar Menu' ),
    //'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
));
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Code:

```css
.site-nav {
  background: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #b5b5b5;
}

.site-nav nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-page_ancester a:link,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-page_ancester a:visited {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-nav ul,
.main-nav li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav a {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid #080808;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}

.main-nav ul ul a {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #080808;
}

.main-nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.main-nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999999px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #b5b5b5;
}

.main-nav ul li:hover>ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}

.main-nav ul ul li:hover>ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 140px;
}

.main-nav li.has-children>a:after {
  color: #000000;
  content: ' ↓';
  font-size: 15px;
  vertical-align: 0px;
}

.main-nav li li.has-children>a:after {
  color: #000000;
  content: ' →';
  font-size: 15px;
  vertical-align: 1px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul id="menu-primary" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-9"><a href="http://url_address/testfolder/wordpresstestfolder/" aria-current="page">Home</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-6"><a href="http://url_address/testfolder/wordpresstestfolder/index.php/sample-page/">Sample Page</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="http://url_address/testfolder/wordpresstestfolder/index.php/test/">test</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="http://url_address/testfolder/wordpresstestfolder/index.php/test-2/">test 2</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="http://url_address/testfolder/wordpresstestfolder/index.php/test-3/">test 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please can you create a [mcve] showing your html too

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please see the edit above. As it's a wordpress theme, there's not a lot of code required to show the menu. I can view the source of the page and post that if required.

Comment: You need to go to your rendered page a view source and show that html, showing the wordpress source doesn't help us create a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry about that. Added the code as a 2nd edit above.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Question was answered below. I feel like kind of an idiot for missing something so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Bro Use this css for current-menu style

```
.site-nav nav ul li.current-menu-item > a:link,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-menu-item > a:visited,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-page_ancester > a:link,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-page_ancester > a:visited {
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have that in the code, but it isn't making a difference.

Comment: Ok, so I'm an idiot. I was missing the > in the code. Can't believe I missed something so simple. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
.site-nav nav ul ul li {

    background: white;

    a {

        color: black;

    }

}
```

You will need to add additional code within here to cater for active menu items and hover etc

Sorry that is using Sass.  If you are not familiar with that then:

```
.site-nav nav ul ul li {

    background: white;

}

.site-nav nav ul ul li a {

    color: black;

}
```